I can't fetch full transactions for Solana token from quicknode api. Some signatures are missing
I am trying fetch all the signatures of a solana token with details. I am using monthly subscription. But Its failed to give full transactions. Some signatures are missing.Same happening with heilius.
async function fetchSignatures(mintAddress, endpoint) {
  const connection = new Connection(endpoint, 'confirmed');
  let allSignatures = [];
  let beforeSignature = null;
  const batchSize = 1000;

  while (true) {
    const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
      new PublicKey(mintAddress),
      { limit: batchSize, before: beforeSignature }
    );

    if (signatures.length === 0) break;

    allSignatures = allSignatures.concat(signatures);
    beforeSignature = signatures[signatures.length - 1].signature;

    console.log(`Fetched ${signatures.length} signatures, total so far: ${allSignatures.length}`);
  }
}


Hi @Ruba haider, DevRel from QuickNode here. I would like to dive deeper into this to help you
Can you please provide the token's mint address and an example of your missing signature?

Hi @Sahil Here is the mint:Fc8tnLTMaZaktR9xXGCEP9zemEScvGNUQVUMdmjrsikM. For example ,this wallet is missing:https://solscan.io/account/H4jcsvPc72sw4Y41FJ4XLtKaFz4LQwPXkHYw8xmJAEK8

This can be an issue when the accounts are in the lookup table rather than the accounts list. A solution would be to handle the lookup table or get all the associated token holders and then get their signatures (this will be a slow and comprehensive process).
Something like this:
import { Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';

async function fetchSignatures(mintAddress, endpoint) {
  const connection = new Connection(endpoint, 'confirmed');
  const mintPublicKey = new PublicKey(mintAddress);
  let allSignatures = [];
  const batchSize = 1000;

  // Fetch signatures for the mint address
  await fetchSignaturesForAddress(connection, mintPublicKey, allSignatures, batchSize);

  // Fetch all token accounts for the mint
  const tokenAccounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    {
      filters: [
        {
          dataSize: 165,  // size of token account
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 0,
            bytes: mintPublicKey.toBase58(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  console.log(`Found ${tokenAccounts.length} token accounts for this mint`);

  // Fetch signatures for each token account
  for (const tokenAccount of tokenAccounts) {
    await fetchSignaturesForAddress(connection, tokenAccount.pubkey, allSignatures, batchSize);
  }

  console.log(`Total signatures fetched: ${allSignatures.length}`);
  return allSignatures;
}

async function fetchSignaturesForAddress(connection, address, allSignatures, batchSize) {
  let beforeSignature = null;

  while (true) {
    const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
      address,
      { limit: batchSize, before: beforeSignature }
    );

    if (signatures.length === 0) break;

    allSignatures.push(...signatures);
    beforeSignature = signatures[signatures.length - 1].signature;

    console.log(`Fetched ${signatures.length} signatures for address ${address.toBase58()}, total so far: ${allSignatures.length}`);
  }
}

// Usage
const mintAddress = 'Fc8tnLTMaZaktR9xXGCEP9zemEScvGNUQVUMdmjrsikM';
const endpoint = 'https://node-sub-domain.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/'; // Replace with your preferred RPC endpoint
fetchSignatures(mintAddress, endpoint);

